# Python Flask session variables aren't recognized by imported functions

Tags: python, flask

My Flask application.py was getting a bit large and I wanted to spread the content (classes/functions) across a couple of additional py files.  I placed  class definitions in an appClasses.py and that is imported fine by application.py using

```
from appClasses import *
```

And, I placed some function definitions into appFunction.py and import those into application.py using

```
from appFunction import *
```

The functions in appFunction.py make use of flask session variables.  When the same functions are in application.py there is no issue with session variable references (and app behaves as expected) but as soon as I cut/paste into appFunction.py and import functions I get a name error exception when the first function using session vars is called:

> NameError: name 'session' is not defined

Here's a sample function:

```
def load_hgw_dict():
    print("LOAD HGW DICT: called")
    if 'hgw_dict_loaded' in session:
        print("LOAD HGW DICT: hgw dict is available")
        hgw_dict=session['hgw_dict']
    else:
        print("LOAD HGW DICT: hgw dict not available...adding")
        session['hgw_dict_loaded']=True
        list_of_hgws="/home/stbweb/LIST_OF_HENBGW"
        hgw_file = open(list_of_hgws, "r")
        hgw_dict=dict()
        for line in hgw_file:
            hgw_common, hgw_ip, hgw_hostname = line.split()
            hgw_dict[hgw_common]= { 'ip':hgw_ip, 'hostname':hgw_hostname }
        hgw_file.close()
        print("LOAD HGW DICT: hgw dict =", hgw_dict)
    return hgw_dict
```

Session is created by flask itself when flask application.py is run. 
Here's the project dir structure...some files removed for compactness

```
. 
|-- appClasses.py 
|-- appHeNBGW.py 
|-- application.ini 
|-- application.py 
|-- application.pyc 
|-- cert.pem 
|-- flask_session 
|   -- 2029240f6d1128be89ddc32729463129 
|-- __init.py__ 
|-- key.pem 
|-- __pycache__ 
|<snip> 
|-- README.md 
|-- set_dev_env 
|-- static |<snip> 
|-- templates 
| <snip>  
 -- wsgi.py
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? What is the project directory structure? Where is the session defined? What do your `__init__.py` files look like?

Comment: @Yserbius edited post with requested info.

Comment: It looks like there's a circular dependency. `application.py` needs a function from `appFunction.py` which needs the `session` variable from `application.py`. I would suggest re-writing the functions to take a session variable, like `def load_hgw_dict(session):`, then you can pass the session from `application.py`.